# Purpose of the initial variable in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
 evens_to_50 = [i for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0]
 print evens_to_50
```

Can someone explain the **i** that stands directly after the closed bracket and before the **for** in the first row of this code, or share a link or a guide that explains such codes; All I found is a general explanation (not for python, but programmering in general) but nothing too specific; I understand (I think) how the **for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0** but not the **i** part before it.

Comment: It's in your title, that's a list comprehension.

Comment: I googled that, and didn't find anything I could understand.

Comment: well, you might want to make a list of even numbers: `[2*i for i in range(51)]`, so you've got to have an expression based on `i` there.

Comment: `i` is each number in  the range `0 -50`, you keep each i that is even, that i you keep is the first i in the lis comp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first `i` after the open bracket represents the value that will be stored in the list. The other `i's` that appear are just loop variables. Technically, they are all loop control variables, however, the first `i` is the one that will be stored in the list.

Comment: So, an accumulator of sorts. I think I get it; Thank you!

Comment: No, not at all an accumulator. It's an expression that, when evaluated, will be inserted into the output list. That expression is evaluated once per loop iteration but doesn't have any relation to the values before or after it. For another example: `["I like " + i for i in ['cats', 'dogs', 'people']]` returns `["I like cats", "I like dogs", "I like people"]`.

Comment: Say you were giving a list of words and you wanted to create a new list of these words in lower case, you could do `lowercase = [ word.lower() for word in wordList]`. You are able to manipulate the first instance of the loop variable. I think this is the most important thing to understand about list  comprehensions.

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension is just shorthand for some equivalent for loop.

```
[i for i in range(3)]
```

means:

```
result = []
for i in range(3):
    result.append(i)
```

The list comprehension just constructs the list in one go **anonymously**, that is without assigning it a name (like `result` in the example above).

The answer to what that first `i` does is that it answers the question "What do I add to the list on each iteration defined by the following loop?"

Try these comprehensions to see what you get:

```
['c' for i in range(3)]
[2*i for i in range(3)]
['hello'[i] for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write list comprehensions you have to provide a value that you want returned for each iteration of the loop (what will end up populating the result list), then the loop you're running.  At it's most basic form, that looks like this:

```
[i for i in range(10)]
```

Which just means "use the value I'm iterating over as the return value each time and put that into my list."  You don't *have* to be this simplistic.  If you were generating a list of tuples, for example, it might look like this:

```
[(i, False) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i` you are referring to is what values will be inserted in to your new list you are creating. A list comprehension creates a new list for you, and that `i` is what will be in that new list. To break down your list comprehension that you pasted in to english, what you are saying (from left to right) is:

Take the value `i` in to a new list, for each value of `i` in the range of numbers from 0 - 50, but only the even numbers, i.e. `i % 2 = 0`

Or to re-word it again:

for each value in the range of 0-50 (`range(51)`), only those numbers that are even (`i % 2 = 0`), insert each number (each number represented by `i`) in to the new list (`[]`):

```
[i for i in range(51) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the value that will be included in your list for each iteration.

For example, try changing it to `i + 1`, and all your resulting list values should be higher by 1.